# What does this mean: Loaded += MyWindow_Loaded;

Tags: c#, .net

i have a vb.net background and trying to learn c# syntax

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means you are subscribing to the event `Loaded`, and the event listener is `MyWindow_Loaded` method in your class.

Answer (score 10):

That is the same as saying:

```
AddHandler Me.Loaded, AddressOf(MyWindow_Loaded)
```

Though in your code it may be part of the method declaration like this:

```
Private Sub MyWindowLoaded(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Loaded
    ...
End Sub
```

Either way, it means that you're attaching the function named `MyWindow_Loaded` to the `Loaded` [event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645739%28VS.71%29.aspx).

Comment: adam, can you explain that line please :)

Answer (score 3):

Although you can easily understand what it's supposed to do, the syntax can be a bit puzzling. Making an addition between an event and a method doesn't really make sense, but the effect is of course that an event handler is attached to the event.

The += operator for an event attaches an event handler to the event. However, there is a shortcut that the compiler does here to convert the method to a delegate. The actual generated code (that you also can use) is something like:

```
Loaded += new LoadedEventHandler(MyWindow_Loaded);
```

So, what the code does is to create an event handler delegate for the method, and attaches it to the event. The type of the delegate is determined by what the event expects.

Answer (score 2):

It attaches the method `MyWindow_Loaded` to the event `Loaded`. Please [see this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645739(VS.71).aspx) for more info.